# xjc fails to generate classes when using bindings

Tags: java, jaxb

This used to work with all previous versions of JAXB. I've upgraded to version 2.2.7 of JAXB and now `xjc` throws the following:

> java.lang.AssertionError: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException - with linked exception:   [com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1
> counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
> com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter is an interface, and JAXB
> can't handle interfaces.
> this problem is related to the following location:
> at com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter
> at public com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BIGlobalBinding.nameConverter
> at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BIGlobalBinding
> ]

Answer (score 5):

As of jaxb 2.2.7 they have split the jaxb libraries into several components. xjc is now decoupled from any particular jaxb runtime. To fix this issue, ensure a jaxb runtime is made available on the classpath when executing xjc. Details can be found on their release notes here: https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.7/docs/release-documentation.html#a-2-2-7

The reference implementation can be found on maven central with the following coordinate:
com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7

Comment: link is broken, redirect points to a plain implementation of jaxb-v2 and answer provides no clue as to what? is miss configured and where?

Answer (score 2):

As the whole JAXB project now moved from https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2 to https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri including the Maven dependencies, I updated my `pom.xml` from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb-xjc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb-xjc.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This helped me at least with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you are using Eclipse or a derivative (websphere studio, jDeveloper, Spring Tools Suite, ...). If not, you may use the JDK ['xjc' command line tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html), else the [Maven Plug-in JAXB2](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/))

You have to explicitly configure JAXB for the project (different projects may bear different configs to make things simple!)

In recent Eclipse version (4.4+) follow these steps:

- ensure the [Eclipse Web Tools platform](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) is installed in Eclipse
- apply the JAXB facet to your Eclipse project containing the .xsd schemas to transform into jaxb classes; right-click project > properties > Project Facets > JAXB; further configuration is available and lets you select which library supplies the JAXB implementation (recent JRE has it) as well as the JAXB version. > OK > Apply.
- select the .xsd file at stake, right-click > generate > JAXB classes ... at minimum supply a package name (e.g. draw it from the XSD namespace) > Finish
- the Eclipse console view provides feedback on generated files